# How to quote coulmn name in zend db?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

How to quote column name like $column and $sorting

```
$result = $this 
    -> select() 
    -> from($this -> _name, new Zend_Db_Expr('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *'))
    -> order("$column $sorting") 
    -> limit("$start, $limit") 
    -> query() 
    -> fetchAll();
```

in this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quoteIdentifier()` in `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract`:

```
$columnSafe = $adapter->quoteIdentifier($column);
$sortingSafe = in_array(strtoupper($sorting) , array('ASC', 'DESC')) ? $sorting : 'ASC'; //default to ASC if illegal value passed
```

Comment: its return this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`id`' in 'order clause'' in

Comment: What is the schema of your table then? Does it have an `id` column?

Comment: Are you selecting from the right table? You can debug your select statement if you just `echo $select` - you will have to assign it to a variable before doing `fetchAll()`

Comment: Well, as I wrote earlier, dump your select statement and check if it is correct and if the column is escaped properly. If so, my work here is done and you're welcome to accept my answer and post a new question on why your query is still not working.